# Trouble with Vitis Model Composer 2023.2! MATLAB R2021b crashes when I want to open the Model Composer Hub component

Tags: 22.04, matlab

I'm a fresh Ubuntu and AMD Vitis user! My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, and my system graphic card is Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2). Recently I installed AMD Vitis 2023.2 and Matlab R2021b, and I've also checked about the version compatibility, It seems that they are compatible.
I checked this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Xilinx/Vitis_Model_Composer/tree/2023.2/Tutorials/HDL_Library) and I just wanted to get started with the model composer, once it was set up, it got stuck in the HDL code-generating step. So I was forced to close the Matlab window. after that every time I tried to open the Model Composer Hub settings window I encountered this error: Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type. and in the Matlab command window, the thread of errors comes up like this:

```
MathWorks::System::IUserException in WebControllerFactory::create(): [Error using matlab.internal.cef.webwindow (line 396)
MATLABWindow application failed to launch. Unable to launch the MATLABWindow application. The exit code was: 127
Error in matlab.internal.webwindow/createImplementation (line 313)
   implObj = matlab.internal.cef.webwindow(varargin{:});
Error in matlab.internal.webwindow (line 161)
   obj.impl = obj.createImplementation(varargin{:}); 
Error in matlab.ui.internal.controller.platformhost.CEFFigurePlatformHost/createView (line 65)
   this.CEF = matlab.internal.webwindow(peerModelInfo.URL, peerModelInfo.DebugPort, 
   position);
Error in matlab.ui.internal.controller.FigureController/createView (line 451)
   this.PlatformHost.createView(this.PeerModelInfo, pos, title, visible, resizable, 
   windowState, windowStyle);
Error in matlab.ui.internal.componentframework.WebComponentController/add (line 78)
   obj.createView( parentController, parentView, pvPairs );
Error in matlab.ui.internal.controller.WebCanvasContainerController/add (line 43)
   add@matlab.ui.internal.componentframework.WebContainerController( this, webComponent, 
   parentController );
Error in matlab.ui.internal.componentframework.WebControllerFactory/create (line 94)
   component.createController( parentController, [] );
Error in vmcHub/createProgressBar
Error in vmcHub/createComponents
Error in vmcHub
Error in vmcHubCallback]
```

as you can see in the attached picture:

[image: MATLAB Command Window Errors]

[image: Dot Indexing Error]

According to my research in different forums, I tried to launch `MATLABWindow` from this directory `~/MATLAB/R2021b/bin/glnxa64` this error came up:

```
 [0212/032751.828388:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

[image: Terminal Error due to launch MATLABWindow]

Now I just wanna ask if is there anyone who can help me.

Comment: "InitializeSandbox() called" is not a problem. I see it all the time starting a browser. Your app uses an embedded browser. The problem is it can't load the webpage shown by "Access to XMLHttpRequest". The fix would be to check any network connections, firewalls, proxies, etc. for problems

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you please explain it more?

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't have Vitis installed. My point was that I think it's either a problem with your internet connection or that Xilinx servers are down (unlikely that they are *still* down)

Answer (score 0):

Vitis 2023.2 is only supported by Ubuntu up to 24.04.2 (read UG973) and even if it looks silly, you really must stick to that. Xilinx (now AMD) software is really picky about that.
[image]

Comment: The current up-to-date point release of Ubuntu 22.04 is Ubuntu 22.04.4.

Comment: Again: Vitis 2023.2 is only supported by Ubuntu up to 24.04.2

Comment: The purpose of my comment was to prevent this answer from being deleted, not the opposite,